# Voltage loss on drain to source using PSMN7R5-60YLX

Tags: mosfet

I am using a IR2101S to drive a [PSMN7R5-60YLX](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/nexperia-usa-inc/PSMN7R5-60YLX/5981426?s=N4IgTCBcDaIA4GcC2A7A7AJwKwFoBsADAJ4A2AHiALoC%2BQA) logic level N-channel MOSFET.  My battery is 12.59V but the motor is only receiving 7.62 volts.  The signal coming out of the IR2101 is exactly 5V to the gate of PSMN7R5-60YLX.  Can someone teach me how to read this datasheet to figure out why I'm losing so much voltage?

Here is my schematic:

[image: Circuit]

Comment: The schematic shows +12V, yet you measured 5? What are the waveforms?

Comment: No, the IR2101S puts out a 5V logic going to the gate of Q1 as it should. I measure the correct 5V on LO.

Comment: What is the expected motor current?

Comment: The schematic shows the same supply to motor and driver, so either you're not supplying 12V to both, or you're driving some duty cycle into it, or the schematic is wrong.

Comment: It is the same supply, 12V battery.  The gate is what is driven by the IR2101S pin which puts out 5V.  The motor without anything on the shaft draws almost 5 amps, stall current is 24 amps.

Comment: @mScientist, the main spec of the transistor relevant here is RDSon. At 5V VGS, it is 9m ohm (max). Even with 24amp, this is only 0.216V. If you are seeing such high drop in a static DC condition, do you have high routing resistance between motor to transistor drain or transistor source to ground causing such increased drop?

Comment: @sai I do have some lengthy wiring.  This is on my test bench so I could try to cut out some wire resistance and see what happens.

Comment: Would it be possible to use the other driver of the IR2101S to drive another mosfet for braking?   If so, how would I implement that connection wise?

Comment: Also, if I happen to NOT have the 12V going to operate the IR2101S but keep the 12V to the motor the MOSFET gets really really hot.  Is that normal?  I wouldn't think it would be conducting anything.

Comment: I think the MOSFET is broken

Comment: It stays nice and cool as long as I also have the IR2101S powered and still works as expected when testing.  I was just curious as to why it would happen.  Now I need to see if I can use the other driver part of the IR2101S and using another PSMN7R5-60YLX as a brake.  Anyone know how I can hook that up?  I do have another I/O to control  it with. I'm just not sure how to hook it up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are not feeding the gate driver IC with a PWM signal, and it's just on all the time (LIN is permanently low), then:

- LO should be high, at +12V, not +5V.
- The MOSFET should be fully on, even with +5V at its gate.

Since you have 0Ω between LO and the gate, it's not possible to say if the MOSFET is dragging the gate voltage down, or the IR2101 is unable to pull the gate up to +12V. However, since the transistor should be on even with +5V at the gate, and it clearly isn't...

My money is on the MOSFET being dead.

Comment: I'm not thinking its the IR2101 being dead.  without the MOSFET hooked up I get 5V from LO.  I have tried two chips.  I will try a third.

Comment: You should get +12V out of LO, without anything connected. And with 5V at the MOSFET gate, the MOSFET should be completely on. Neither of these things happen, so maybe both are bad.

Comment: The MOSFET did die.  I do believe it was from the incorrect use of the IR2101S.  I have replaced the MOSFET and gotten rid of the IR2101S altogether.

Answer (score 0):

The key specification of interest here for the transistor is RDSon. At 5V VGS, it is 9m ohm (max) as per the datasheet that you provided. Even with 24amp, this is only 0.216V. If you are seeing such high drop in a static DC condition and if the transistor is not damaged, it should be the IR drop somewhere on the high current path. You could use a multimeter and check across different sections of the high current path to see where the extra drop of ~5V is present. An extra routing resistance of 200m ohm can cause such a drop.