# Is it possible to use two N-channel MOSFETs as motor driver with one driving and the other being used as a brake?

Tags: mosfet

I have two [PSMN7R5-60YLX](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/nexperia-usa-inc/PSMN7R5-60YLX/5981426?s=N4IgTCBcDaIA4GcC2A7A7AJwKwFoBsADAJ4A2AHiALoC%2BQA) and also using a [IR2101S](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/infineon-technologies/IR2101SPBF/856494).  I can use the 2101 and the MOSFET to drive the motor just using one of the drivers on the chip.  Is the circuit below correct to use one as a brake (the bottom one) as long as I put a small delay before turning on the brake? Would this circuit work without giving me problems?

[image: Possible Circuit]

Comment: Your driver circuit will not work. EEs look at the detail (if that helps you understand an EEs mentality) and, questions that propose faulty looking circuits should be fixed first.

Comment: Top MOSFET will be impossible to bootstrap so you won’t be able to fully turn it on. You need Q5 gate to be higher than 12 V.

Comment: This circuit worked not using HO, R8, R9 and Q5 with the motor above Q4 with 12V at the 1 of the motor.  How should it be connected?

Comment: These are logic level mosfets.  LO and HO put out a 5V signal.

Comment: @mScientist How would your IR2101 know that those are logic-level FETs? It's connected to 12V, so it'll output 12V gate drive signals. This circuit really won't work like this - at least not for long. The motor might spin for a while until Q5 burns out. For a quick fix, connect 18V to the IR2101's VB input. For a more thorough / robust fix, connect VS to Q5's source and put a floating 12V power supply between VS and VB (this is how the IR2101 is intended to be used).

Comment: I have no clue then. Part of asking to learn I guess.  I do know in this question [link](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/658887/voltage-loss-on-drain-to-source-using-psmn7r5-60ylx?noredirect=1#comment1751661_658887) it works. For some reason with that circuit it is outputting 5V on LO.

Comment: I just retested.  With everything 12V except for the LIN being 5V I get 5V out of LO (actually 4.6V).

Comment: What does the waveform of LO look like?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have a scope, I'm just measuring the voltage with a multi-meter.

Comment: Okay, so definitely not getting the same response with HO.  It is definitely different with VB going to 12V.

Comment: It's nearly impossible to do proper troubleshooting and design analysis without a scope. Is LIN actually 5V DC? Try measuring LO using an AC setting on the DMM. If it's a really cheap meter, it may not be capacitively coupled, and it might not even have less than a 200V range.

Comment: Since the MOSFETS are logic level would it be suitable to just get rid of the IR2101S?  If so, I do think I would then need a gate resistor but how do I determine the value?

Comment: I just found that I had a Xminilab Portable scope.  I have it charging and will test again when charging is complete.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can brake like this, although you should probably add a resistor in series with the drain of Q4 to dissipate the energy that the motor generates while spinning down (it acts as a generator during that time).

There's a huge problem with your circuit, though: You can't actually use the IR2101 to drive the high-side MOSFET like that. The MOSFET will just overheat and die because it gets insufficient gate voltage when the motor is turned on. You need a different MOSFET driver or a floating supply for the bootstrap voltage. Alternatively, you could connect an 18V supply to VB, but that requires your 12V supply to never get any higher than 12V (using a lead-acid battery is out of the question, for example).

Check out [this article](https://www.analog.com/en/technical-articles/powering-the-isolated-side-of-your-half-bridge-configuration.html) from Analog Devices for more info on how to wire up the high side driver in an N-MOS-only half-bridge. (You'll have to use a dedicated isolated supply, such as a standard 1W isolated DC/DC brick.) Note that you can't use a regular bootstrap circuit since those can't keep the high-side MOSFET on for extended periods of time.

Comment: what value of resistor would you recommend and why (I need to learn this :) )?  FYI, the motor has a stall current of 24A.  Running with nothing on the shaft it runs almost at 5A.

Comment: I have gotten rid of the IR2101S altogether since I am using Logic level MOSFETS. Looking at the datasheet what should I be looking at to calculate a good gate resistor to protect my I/O pin?  My I/O pin needs to stay about 20mA.

Comment: Removing the IR2101S makes the problem even worse. The motor is connected to the high-side MOSFET's source terminal. To turn it on fully, its gate voltage must be higher than the source voltage. Since the motor is supplied with 12V, the voltage at the gate of the high-side MOSFET must be higher than 12V. For your MOSFETs in particular, it must be at least 5V higher, which means that you have to apply at least 17V to the gate (but less than the maximum of 20V). Hence my suggestion to use an 18V supply for the VB pin of the IR2101S.

Comment: I guess I am confused about what a logic level mosfet is.  I had the understanding that a logic level mosfet could be turned on and off with 5V/0V.

Comment: That's correct. The problem is that voltages are always relative - you always need a reference point. The microcontroller outputs 5V with respect to ground, while the MOSFET expects 5V on its gate with respect to its *source terminal*. If you connect source to ground, that's totally fine, both have the same reference. In your case, though, source is connected to the motor, which is at 12V (to ground) when switched on. Those 5V with respect to ground are actually -7V with respect to the MOSFET's source in that case.

Comment: I don't know how to do/fix this. Does anyone have an example of a circuit that is correct for using two N channel mosfets (one to drive, the other to brake) using a microcontroller.  All I seem to find are H-bridge circuits that use P channel mosfets.

Comment: You already have the correct MOSFET driver for this. The IR2101 is intended to do exactly that: Drive a half-bridge made from two N-MOSFETs. All you have to do is wire it up according to its datasheet. See: https://www.analog.com/en/technical-articles/powering-the-isolated-side-of-your-half-bridge-configuration.html (You need a dedicated isolated supply, such as a 1W, 12V-to-12V isolated DC/DC brick.)

Comment: Thanks @Jonathan S.  Interesting article.  My circuit is running off a 12V 35Amp Hr car battery then through proper voltage regulation down to micro-controller voltage for operation.  The motor power is also being supplied by the same 12V battery so the grounds are definitely connected.  Does this change things as the article describes mostly where the circuits are isolated.  BTW, thanks for your patience and continuing to slap knowledge into me.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/144669/discussion-between-jonathan-s-and-mscientist).

Answer (score 0):

The datasheet for the IR2101 shows how to implement a bootstrap circuit to provide voltage for the high side MOSFET. And you can drive the low side with 100% duty cycle for braking, although the bootstrap will not be working, and that might trigger the undervoltage shutdown for the high side. You will need to drive HIN and LIN with complementary PWM signals.

[image]

(from datasheet)